# VS building DLL and EXE?

Tags: c#, build

I'm trying to build a console program with just a single executable file (TPProcMon.exe) but for some reason it is creating an executable *and* a dll (TPProcMon.exe *and* TPProcMon.dll). If I attempt move TPProcMon.exe to a new folder and run it from there it throws an error `The application to execute does not exist: 'Folder\Where\Exe\Moved\To\TPProcMon.dll'`

This not a behavior I want nor do I have any idea why it is doing this. I want an executable, not a dll with an executable as a wrapper.

My csproj looks like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>False</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="TouchPortal-CS-API" Version="1.45.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see I've tried setting ProduceReferenceAssembly to False and PublishSingleFile to True but it still, without fail, makes the exe *and* dll file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try single-file deployment, detailed by MS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)? I was able to get this to work with a .NET 7 console app, but it only took effect on publish, not simply on build.

Comment: This behavior is by design and is described in [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#produce-a-cross-platform-binary)